# C++ map with adjacent_difference

Tags: c++, algorithm

Really confused by some errors I'm getting related to using a `std::map` container with a call to `std::adjacent_difference`. The documentation for [adjacent_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference) says the following about defining a custom operator:

> op    -   binary operation function object that will be applied.
>
> The signature of the function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> Ret fun(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
>
> The signature does not need to have const &.
> The types Type1 and Type2 must be such that an object of type
> iterator_traits::value_type can be implicitly converted to both of them. The
> type Ret must be such that an object of type OutputIt can be dereferenced and assigned a
> value of type Ret.

So in the following code (snippet), I have a lambda that returns an integer to a final container to hold the differences between values stored in the map.

```cpp
  std::map<char, int> m;
  // Do stuff to initialize map contents here
  // ...
  std::vector<int> d;
  typedef std::pair<char, int> P;
  std::adjacent_difference(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(d),
   [](const P & a, const P & b)->int { return std::abs(a.second - b.second);}
  );
```

And I get some error that is clearly referring to an invalid assignment made between a pair and an integer. Not how I interpreted the documentation, and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I thought the documentation was pretty clear in saying the return value of the lambda is assigned to the result container, but clearly that is not what's happening?

```
/usr/local/include/c++/8.3.0/bits/stl_numeric.h:374:17: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<int> >’ and ‘_ValueType’ {aka ‘std::pair<const char, int>’})
       *__result = __value;
       ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

Have I crossed my wires somewhere else?

Comment: try `typedef std::pair<const char, int> P;`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but after trying I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Studying the cppreference link you provided shows that `std::adjacent_difference()` cannot transform its output to a type different from the input:

> both acc (the accumulated value) and the result of val - acc or
> op(val, ACC) <...> must be writable to OutputIt.

So, to use algorithms, you would first need to use `std::transform()` to convert the map into `std::vector<int>`, and next use `std::adjacent_difference()`. But a manual loop will probably make more sense.

Comment: I think cppreference is uncharacteristically obtuse on this requirement. **"3) First, creates an accumulator acc whose type is InputIt's value type, initializes it with *first, and assigns the result to *d_first"**  is the other easy to miss clue.